# how to clear the ArrayList after adding that ArrayList to HashMap in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, hashmap, expandablelistview

Am doing one small android app. In that i have **Expandable listview** and am trying to populate data's from **SQLite.** So that i used **HashMap** to store `parent(String)` and `child(ArrayList)`.

For eg I have four integer no's in parent(1, 2, 3, 4) i get this and stored in ListArray. Now i need to get child(ListArray) for that particular parent. Parent 1 contain (aa, bb), parent 2 contain (cc).. etc, now see this code

```
try 
    {
        header = new ArrayList<String>();
        footer = new ArrayList<String>();
        child= new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        String date = null;

        int count=0, countchild=0;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Date FROM Table", null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            do 
            {
                date=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Date"));
                header.add(date);
                count=count+1;

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        {
            String temp=header.get(i);
            Cursor cc=db.rawQuery("SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE Date ='"+ temp +"' ", null);
            if(cc.moveToFirst())
            {
                do 
                {
                    countchild=countchild+1;
                    String id=cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("Id"));
                    //footer.clear();   // it clear all data's on child
                    footer.add(id);
                    Log.d("Footer date count", "" + countchild);
                    child.put(temp, footer);
                } 
                while (cc.moveToNext());

                //footer.clear();  // it clear all data's on child
            }
            footer.clear();     // it clear all data's on child
        }

    }
```

I want to clear **footer** here after adding it to child then only i will get proper **Expandable listview**. If i remove/comment this `footer.clear()` line then all child's are added to all parents. *eg parent 1 contain (aa, bb, cc, etc) and parent 2 contain (aa, bb, cc, etc)*. If i leave this `footer.clear()` line then all child's are cleared and display only parent like this eg Parent 1(), Parent 2()... etc

How to clear this `footer(ListArray)` after adding it to **HashMap** ?? or tell me some suggestion to modify this code.

Thank you. Srihari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `put` the `ArrayList` to the `HashMap`, the `HashMap` actually saves a reference to your array, not a copy.

That's why you must use different arrays for each group:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    List<String> children = new ArrayList<String>();
    String temp = header.get(i);
    Cursor cc = db.rawQuery("SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE Date ='"+ temp +"' ", null);
    if(cc.moveToFirst())
    {
        countChild += cc.getCount();
        Log.d("Footer date count", "" + countchild);
        do
        {
            String id = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("Id"));
            children.add(id);
            child.put(temp, children);
        }
        while (cc.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

As you can see a new `children` `ArrayList` here is created for each group and it's never `clear`ed as that would clear the values from `HashMap` also.

Furthermore I've let myself fix a few other things like using `Cursor`'s `getCount` method, to get the count instead of looping. Also I'm not using the `footer` array as it's unnecessary in the code you've shown.

Lastly, please use understandable and meaningful names for your variables as it can help you as well as others who read your code.

Comment: Hi @user3249477 thanks a lot, now i understood and thank you for your suggestion hereafter i use exact name for variables. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember Java is OO so if you clear an instance of an object, in this case an ArrayList, every other object referencing to it will get that new value.

What I recommend is you create a new instance of your footer variable everytime you need to fill a new group of your expandable list view, that way every footer list instance you create will be "associated" with one group in your list.

Hope this helps. :)